# Is it possible to merge a django model class with a ManyToMany relation?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have inherited a large Django application and it features this idiom in the model for the "shows" application:

```
class Movie_Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    # More fields here...

    players = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='playlists_played', null=True, blank=True)

class PlaylistPlayer(models.Model):
    user           = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='play_links')
    movie_playlist = models.ForeignKey(Movie_Playlist, related_name='playlist_plays')
    count          = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_played    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'shows_movie_playlist_players'
```

As near as I can tell, the idea may be that the shows_movie_playlist_players table (which would be created by the ManyToManyField relation) is supposed to do double duty by storing per-user information in addition to just the relationship itself. Certainly, there seem to only be two related tables in the original database: "shows_movie_playlist" and "shows_movie_playlist_players".

Also, for what it's worth, this "validates" fine in Django 1.2.3 -- 1.3.1.

This would all be fine and dandy, except that it breaks the "python manage.py test" method when it tries to create the test database since the shows_movie_playlist_players has already been created by the "ManyToManyField..." specification by the time it gets to the PlaylistPlayer class.

If I comment out the "ManyToManyField..." line, I can create the test database and run tests with no problem. Otherwise, I get this:

```
> python manage test shows -v3
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_production')...
Creating tables ...
Creating table shows_movie_playlist_players
Creating table shows_movie_playlist
Creating table shows_movie_playlist_players
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
    ... Lots of tracebackage here...
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'shows_movie_playlist_players' already exists")
```

So is this a properly specified relation and overridden table that just doesn't have support for testing yet or is something horribly wrong?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow... I feel for you :) Yes, it's horribly wrong but it might have a simple solution.
Basically it's a hack which tries to accomplish the "through" functionality of a `ManyToManyField`

Try specifying `through='shows.PlaylistPlayer' on the`players` m2m field and see how it behaves then.

Comment: OK! I did this and I could run the tests... Do you think I should get rid of the PlaylistPlayer's Meta class with the db_table specification?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you probably should, but beware that that's going to change the resulting db table name of `PlaylistPlayer` to `shows_playlistplayer`. So if you have an existing DB (say in production) you'll need a schema migration to rename the table from `shows_movie_playlist_players`. It's not a big problem to leave it as is though if you don't want to deal with that yet.

Comment: I think at the moment, I want to make as few changes as possible while still allowing me to get it under test. Thanks very much for your lightning answer!